# How to run scripts in python without using subprocess module? (I don’t have that module)

Tags: python, cmd

How to run cmd codes like `pip install matplotlib` in python?
I tried to use `Stash`, but it costs too much time and it cannot be run if I have a `UIView`. So, can someone help me?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I execute a program or call a system command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command)

Comment: Subprocess is not suitable for me.

Comment: @Doggy - subprocess likely _is_suitable. You've found `os.system` which generally works also, so maybe no big deal. But everything os.system can do, subprocess can do.

Comment: Yea, but my python shell doesn’t have subprocess module (I don’t know why )

Comment: But I have “os” module, and I have that module

Comment: The `subprocess` module is a built-in module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html. It was added since Python 2.4. It is unlikely that your shell doesn't have it.

Comment: But I really don’t have! Umm, maybe I need to update my python, I’ve already 10 years didn’t update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.system` to do that. You use say `os.system(“your command”)`